# How to update the the list of row which I have already found using select from two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I was able to find the rows I need to update with the following code.  The old_ pris is to be updated with the new_pris . 
I am always one step back when it comes to update and insert operations. 
As far as I know I can do a inset into and select statement as I have below for a insertion, but for update!!. Just looking if there is something I should consider looking into.

```
SELECT  o.no as old_no 
      ,o.name as old_name 
      ,n.kid as new_kid     
      ,o.aPris  as old_pris
       ,n.pro_pris as new_pris   

      ,n.id as new_id 

  FROM [db1].[dbv].[tb1] n 
  left join db1.dbv.tb2  o
  on n.barcode =o.code 
   where 
  o.code =n.barcode 
  and o.no !='' 
  and n.barcode !=''
  and o.code!=''
```

the select terms are mixed to let you know the contents of tables I am dealing with. I just need to update the old_pris by new_pris but the join and the where conditions remain same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [**`UPDATE`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms177523.aspx) with `JOIN` like so:

```
UPDATE o
SET o.aPris = n.pro_pris,
    ...
  FROM [db1].[dbv].[tb1] n 
  left join db1.dbv.tb2  o
  on n.barcode =o.code 
   where 
  o.code =n.barcode 
  and o.no !='' 
  and n.barcode !=''
  and o.code!='
```

Comment: Thanks, seems I am having problem here, according to my question you are right, but seems I have a problem. tb1 is mapped to two tb2 products since I know the id for different tb1 products are different. Two same id from tb1 are shown selected list corresponding to the two different products. what must have gone wrong here. I something wrong with my `join` statement. hope you will not mind to say something if you get what mean.

Comment: @tough - Sorry, I couldn't understand. Can you please Edit your question with the three tables' structures and if possible some sample data of them, and explain what is the desired updated result from these tables.